# "Database is too old and upgrade is required" on "technical" databases

Tags: 2013, database, update

An IT admin working for a client installed various Windows patches (along with SP patches available via Windows Update), and now two databases ("BdcServiceDatabase" and "StateDatabase") are showing the dreaded "Database is too old and upgrade is required" message. I've tried running the PSconfig command

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources
```

and while this completed successfully, the databases are still "old". I've also tried running the configuration wizard; that, too, completed successfully, but the databases are still "old". Finally, I've tried running the following

```
(Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.type -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.BdcServiceDatabase"}).Provision()
```

This command completed successfully, but the BdcServiceDatabase (at least) is still "old".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command should fix the `BdcServiceDatabase`:

```
(Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.type -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.BdcServiceDatabase"}).Provision()
```

However, in my case, while actually running the command returned no errors, the command failed silently in the background. Checking the logs it turned out that for some reason the service had no SQL access to the BDC-related database. Adding owner permissions for the service user seemed to clear things up and allowed the `Provision()` to work as expected.